# How to delete a Team Project Collection in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs

I have a Team Project Collection in TFS 2017 that is unused. It was created back, when TFS was new in our Company as a test. So there has never been real Code Checked in or anything. So I want to just delete. I couldn’t find out, how this works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To delete a collection:

1. Detach the collection,
2. Delete the collection database
3. Delete the SharePoint site collection that supported the deleted
   collection.

Please see [Detach or delete a team project collection](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/manage-team-project-collections#detach-or-delete-a-team-project-collection) for details, it's also applied to TFS 2017.

Comment: Answer below is a critical part of this answer; these actions are performed as Daniel states in the TFS admin tool on the TFS server. In addition, if reporting had been enabled, the reports folder should probably also be deleted.  Access reports at URL provided in TFS admin tool in the reports setup step.  SharePoint deletion may not be required if only built-in website function was used, i.e. TFS was not integrated into an existing SharePoint installation, which is likely the case for more recent TFS installations.  Reusing the collection name requires deleting everything.

Answer (score 2):

This is a high-level administrative task that can only be performed by logging into the Application Tier server and using the TFS administration tool.